# Hyperref breaks the index generated by the ltxdoc document class

Tags: hyperref, indexing, documentation

Suppose the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\CodelineIndex
\EnableCrossrefs    
\begin{document}
  \DescribeMacro{\macro}
  A description of \cs{macro}
     \begin{macrocode}
       \macro
%    \end{macrocode}
  \PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

LaTeXing the document as follows

```
pdflatex tex
makeindex -s gind.ist tex
makeindex -s gglo.ist -o tex.gls tex.glo
pdflatex tex
```

produces the following output:

[image: The correct output]

Let's now load the `hyperref` package:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\CodelineIndex
\EnableCrossrefs    
\begin{document}
...
```

LaTeXing the document as described above now results in the following output:

[image: The incorrect output]

The index no longer contains the page number of the macro description. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `hypdoc` loads `hyperref` and adds some "hyper" support for the document class `ltxdoc` with its package `doc`. The index entries are then linked:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\CodelineIndex
\EnableCrossrefs
\begin{document}
...
```

Mind that you need to run the document through LaTeX and `makeindex` at least twice to get correct links within the index:

```
pdflatex tex
makeindex -s gind.ist tex
makeindex -s gglo.ist -o tex.gls tex.glo
pdflatex tex
pdflatex tex
```

Comment: Thank you. The links, however, seem to point to the wrong places. Suppose the following change to our minimal document: `\documentclass{ltxdoc}\usepackage{hypdoc}` ... `\begin{document}text\newpage\DescribeMacro{\macro}` ... Then all the links in the index incorrectly point to the first page. Can this, too, be remedied?

Comment: @Witiko: Try to use `\hypersetup{hypertexnames=false}`, if possible. This is the remedy if `hyperref` is in action, but I have no idea about `hypdoc`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: There is no such issue with `hyperref`, as it doesn't add links to the `ltxdoc`'s index entries. `hypdoc` does, but the index entries all link to the first page.

Comment: @Witiko: Does `hypdoc` have a `\hypersetup` command?

Comment: @Witko I do get correct links. Please make a complete minimal example. Which driver you are using?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Package `hypdoc` loads `hyperref` with some options, thus it "has" `hyperref`'s commands.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: It's fixed now. The `hypdoc` package requires two `latex` + `makeindex` runs instead of just one to resolve the cross-references.

Comment: @Witiko There is a rerun warning: ``Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `test.hd' has changed. Rerun.``

Answer (score 2):

Use the option `hyperindex=false` to prevent the 'wrong' behaviour  of `hyperref` for this.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\CodelineIndex
\EnableCrossrefs    
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \DescribeMacro{\macro}
  A description of \cs{macro}
     \begin{macrocode}
       \macro
%    \end{macrocode}
  \PrintIndex
\end{document}
```